# Positioning of test-path in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a script that sends an email when files are about to reach their max size.

The problem is, that I can't implement a validation check of what the script should do when a file is not found at the given path.

I know that I should implement:

```
if(!(Test-Path $item.Path))
{
   "The file " + $item.Name + " is not found! <br />" 
}
```

But I don't know where to place it exactly (since I'm getting errors all over the place).

**The Code:**

I start with retrieving the files from a config file:

```
$list = foreach ($file in $files)
{   
    $f = Get-Item $file.Path
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{

    Name = $f.Name
    Path = $file.Path
    Size = ($f.Length/$byteSize)
    }
}
```

then I loop through the file list and check their size:

```
foreach ($item in $list)
{
    if($item.Size -gt $item.TriggerSize -And (Test-Path $item.Path))
    {
        #Write-Host $item.Name "Warning! File has reached it's max limit ("$item.Size.ToString(".00")"), The max size is" $item.MaxSize". The trigger size is: " $item.TriggerSize "`r`n"

        $body +=

        "The file " + $item.Name + " is reaching his max size! 
        <br /> Current size: <b>"+$item.Size.ToString(".00") + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1) + "</b>"  + 
        "<br /> Maximum size: " + $item.MaxSize + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1) + "<br /><br />"
    }
}
```

I tried implementing my error check on these places:

```
$list = foreach ($file in $files)
{   

  if(!(Test-Path $item.Path))
        {
           "The file " + $item.Name + " is not found! <br />" 
        }

    $f = Get-Item $file.Path
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{

    Name = $f.Name
    Path = $file.Path
    Size = ($f.Length/$byteSize)
    }
}
```

and here

```
foreach ($item in $list)
{
    if($item.Size -gt $item.TriggerSize -And (Test-Path $item.Path))
    {
        #Write-Host $item.Name "Warning! File has reached it's max limit ("$item.Size.ToString(".00")"), The max size is" $item.MaxSize". The trigger size is: " $item.TriggerSize "`r`n"

        $body +=

        "The file " + $item.Name + " is reaching his max size! 
        <br /> Current size: <b>"+$item.Size.ToString(".00") + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1) + "</b>"  + 
        "<br /> Maximum size: " + $item.MaxSize + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1) + "<br /><br />"
    }

  if(!(Test-Path $item.Path))
    {
       "The file " + $item.Name + " is not found! <br />" 
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error that it's at `Get-Item` that it can't find a file:

the name of the file that I wrote with a false path on purpose: 
**file123.exe**

Error (at the line of the `if(!(Test-Path $file.path))`:

> Get-Item : Cannot find path 'file123.exe' because it does not exist.

Comment: Paste the exact error that you get in PS console, here. Do you mean Get-Item fails even if file exists? How are `$files` and `$list` populated?

Comment: added the error. no everything works fine but I'm trying to 'catch' when a file doesn't exist

Comment: What is the content of `$files` and `$list`? Strings? FileInfo objects? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to error-handle but then your code still passes control to main logic. Instead, you should develop your control flow so that `Get-Item` will be called only when `Test-Path` returns true.

```
$list = foreach ($file in $files)
{   
  if (Test-Path $file.Path) {

    $f = Get-Item $file.Path
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{

      Name = $f.Name
      Path = $f.Path
      Size = ($f.Length/$byteSize)
    }
  } else {
    "The file " + $file.path + " is not found! <br />" 
  }
}
```

And finally, **PROOFREAD YOUR CODE**! You've got `$item.path` tested but `$file.path` accessed. Given your foreach loop, you should have `$file.path` at both places.

Comment: it works but I can't get the file name in your `else`, even if I use `$file` or `$f.Name`

Comment: Use `$file.path` in there. See, proofreading is not enough to do in one part of code - I've missed a variable in my code as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Vesp

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking for file's existence and not catching not found exception. Here's a pseudo that should work:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {     
    try {
        if (!(Test-Path $file.Path)) {
            throw "File $($file.Path) not found"
        }           
        # Rest of the logic
    }
    catch {
        # log error $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

**Update**: Send email whether file exists or not. This is pseudo, excuse syntax please.

Refactor the email sending functionality in separate method, say `Send-Email($content)`. Then:

```
foreach file in files {
    if !(Test-Path file.path) {
        Send-Email -content "File $($file) does does not exist"
    }
    else {
        // your logic here
        if file.size > threshold {
            Send-Email -content "File $($file) exceeded threshold size"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the sending of the mail in the catch

Comment: Tyvm for the answer Nikhil V.